# Ubuntu 14.10 booting problem

Tags: 14.04, boot, login, 14.10

Recently I upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04. After booting from boot loader for the first time, the screen goes black and nothing happens. When I restart it again, a screen prompts which shows

> Unable to Mount, Press S for Recovery or press M for Manual Recovery

On pressing I was able to go to login. This happens always, what is the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Download and burn to cd/dvd a software called [Boot-Repair] from sourceforge.net.  Boot your machine to [Boot-Repair disk] and wait for the screen that gives you 2 boxes you can check, check the box that says [recommended repair] and let the software do its MAGIC. When it is done you will reboot and you should be off and running again. This is a FREE software download and works very well.

Comment: I tried the boot repair disk and it didn't work, I got this: [Boot repair scan](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12387148/) I am going to try another cd with low burning speed this time.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

- Switch on your computer.
- Wait until the Bios has finished loading.
- Press and hold the Shift key.
- Will bring up the Grub menu.
- Select the line which starts with: `Advanced options`.
- Select the line ending with: `recovery mode`,something like:
- Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.16.0-24-generic (recovery mode)
- Press `Enter` and your machine will begin the boot process.
- Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.
- One of the options will be: `Drop to root shell prompt`.
- Press Enter with this option highlighted.

In the terminal run the commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
update-grub
apt-get clean
reboot
```