# Burned dvd 15.04 boot up OK, but burned dvd 14.04.3 doesn't.

Tags: 14.04, boot, dvd

I just tossed away like a pack of dvds just because I couldn't make a dvd iso bootable one for 14.04.

I had no problem burning 15.04 into a dvd, it boots and give you option to install ubuntu. but the 14.04 just doesn't seem to boot, it just resume into windows10.

I have changed the booting order in bios to CDROM
tried to burn with windows10, Nero, and power2go 
I wanted to instal 14.04 as a dual boot with windows 10

sorry for this stupid question, I am new to all of this, is there a difference between 15.04 and 14.04?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, 
Please take a look at this answer it seems similar to you question about booting problems : [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544688/ubuntu-14-10-booting-problem)